# Positive and negative signal paths in the deep learning NN

Tags: neural-networks

I'm new to the deep learning field and I have a question regarding DLNN. It appears that the general approach is to only use positive values and a single (positive) threshold value for the activation function. Why? Why do neurons only increase influence and never decrease it? For the sake of symmetry shouldn't they be able to do it as well?

I could imagine a "negative" network matching the normal one exactly in terms of neurons (kind of the second page) with every "negative" neuron influencing the same path as the "positive" one does, but in a negative way, reducing the resulting value.

[image: Bi-page DLNN]

Comment: What do you mean by “using only positive values”? Also, is DLNN deep learning neural network or something else?

Comment: Yes, DLNN stands for the deep learning neural network. I was reading about activation functions and it looks, maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like the activation only takes place if the value of that function is above a certain positive threshold. Meaning, the neuron is either 0 or 1, which is ok, but it also means they can't suppress the signals from each other. In real life biological neurons can selectively do just that.